# EMMA: Retrieve source later if providing empty emma.sources and how to generate report from coverage.ec

Tags: xml, ant, emma

So I refer "sourcepathref" of instr and report process to a path "emma.sources" which is supposed check for files in **/src/**. However, I need to ignore it for some reasons. So, my "emma.sources" actually contains nothing.

Then I ran the build file, and successfully created metadata.emma and coverage.ec. Now I'm wondering what I can do with that coverage.ec file. How to generate a HTML page from it? Also, as I skipped "sourcepathref" earlier. How do I retrieve all the "sources" for report later?

Thanks a lot!